# Why is Laplace Transform of $\delta(t)$ $F(s)=1$, not $0$ or $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

Let $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, the following integral

$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty \delta(t)e^{-st}dt.
$$

converges to $1$ if $\varepsilon \to -0$ and $0$ if $\varepsilon \to +0$. This shows Laplace Trasform of delta function never converges, while Laplace Transform table says $\delta(t)$ is transformed into 1.

Why is Laplace Transform of $\delta(t)$ $F(s)=1$? Is there any proof or rationale?

Comment: Actually, the Laplace Transform is this integral when $\epsilon \to 0^-$ (it is the definition). So as you said, it is 1.

Comment: @servabat Is there any benefit for that?

Comment: Well, it avoids the particular pitfall you mentioned (by the way, that is a definition, so it's not like some trick).

Comment: There is few explanations. One is that $\delta$ (which is not a function) is the "derivative" of the Heaviside function  which is 0 for t <0 and 1 for t>0. You can apply the classical result of the transform of f'(s) from the transform of f(s) to obtain 1.

Comment: Note: the Dirac $\delta$ is **not** a function.

Comment: @Claudeh5 The same convergence problem seems to occur when I calculate the convergence of Heaviside function at $t \to 0$.

Comment: No ! You have $L(H(t))=\int_0^\infty exp(-st)dt$  as $H(t)=1$ only on R+ and 0 for $t<0$. Then you have $L(H(t))=1/s$. From the result $L(f'(t))=s L(f(t))$, you have $L(\delta(t))=s/s=1$ ($\delta(t)$ is a distribution, not a function)